# setInterval in componentDidUpdate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb

[image]

[image]
Hi! Somewhere in my app.js, when a certain condition gets hit, I update my `toPing` state from false to true so that in the componentDidUpdate, I can check if the state of `toPing` has changed. Only if it changed, then I wanna trigger the setInterval. Am I doing something wrong here because I don't seem to be able to exit the setInterval.

Is this the correct way of implementing setInterval?

BTW, I do not expect my `toPing` state to change again.

Comment: Can you please post your code as text? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

this is true way. are you see output of console log? there is probably a problem with "if"

Comment: pardon let me modify my question

Answer (score 0):

I should `return await ...` otherwise I will never return the promise be it fulfilled or not.